# Is windows server required to build server images?

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances

Very simples .Net5.0 Dockerfiles, builds and runs fine on Windows 10 20H2. But when I push the image to Azure Container, it errors with `New-AzContainerGroup: Unsupported windows image version`. Which sounds like I pushed Windows 10 and not server. Do I need to build this image on a server OS?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

WORKDIR /source

COPY *.csproj .
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

COPY . .
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 3000/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, just need to use the right tagged build that was built on the OS I need. In the dockerfile below, it is the tag `5.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`. That was built with server core ltsc2019. Works in Container Service now.

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

WORKDIR /source

COPY *.csproj .
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

COPY . .
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 3000/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```